# Load and read ply files with Pymesh

Tags: python, ply-file-format

I am trying to load/read a ply file using PyMesh and this line command:

mesh = pymesh.load_mesh("model.obj")

as it is in http://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html.

But this gives me an error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_mesh'".

Am I doing anything wrong? Also I want to know if PyMesh really allows to visualize in 3d the objects.

Thank you.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 14):

If you installed with pip, you might not have gotten the pymesh module you were intending to use. Since you're looking for the load_mesh() method, you'll want to use this installation guide: http://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html.

Comment: @Bárbara Duarte : following the build and install steps in this doc page made it work for me. I am upvoting this answer and suggest you select it as the answer.

Comment: This is definitely the solution to the problem.  The [Python Package Index page for pymesh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymesh) differs is a completely different package that only supports loading STL and OBJ files.  This answer links the appropriate package for the pymesh package the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 8):

There are actually two modules named `pymesh`.

### Pymesh by Takuro Wada

If you install pymesh using `pip` you are installing [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymesh/1.0.2) which has the following [GitHub page.](https://github.com/taxpon/pymesh)

It reads: .sty and .obj

### Pymesh by Qingnan Zhou

If you want to install http://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ you have to follow the installation guidelines [here](http://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

It is more complex, I never manage to get it working, but it should read also .ply.

Comment: I managed to compile https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ with no problem. In Ubuntu 16.04 I only had to manually update my cmake to fulfill dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

On a side note, [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (one of my projects) now supports PLY as well. Install with

```
pip3 install meshio
```

and use on the command line like

```
meshio-convert in.ply out.vtk
```

or from within Python like

```py
import meshio

mesh = meshio.read("in.ply")
# mesh.points, mesh.cells, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are look for `load_mesh()` method, i think that you are looking for [this library](https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh).
This is the related [doc](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

If true, you have to install **pymesh2**

```
pip install pymesh2
```

Otherwise you have to follow the instructions contained in [that page](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) as already suggested, but they are **more complex**.

Answer (score -5):

Either you have not imported the pymesh library

```
import pymesh
```

**OR**

You have a file named **pymesh.py** in your directory where you are executing this file.

If this is the case, then rename the file to some other name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I import pymesh and there isn't a file with name pymesh.py. The import is ok, but the error is about "load_mesh" function. I don't know if I am using the right library, because I find this http://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymesh. Is it the same? The tutorial of each one is different.

Comment: I need to open ply files, but in pymesh page (https://github.com/taxpon/pymesh) says that just opens STL & OBJ. I am confused.

Comment: Alex's answer is more likely the case, pip install pymesh gets a different package than the one OP is looking to use (based on the doc he provides).